# Elastic Search- Search with multiple values with an or condition

Tags: elasticsearch

I have following kind of data indexed into Elastic Search(ES).
{
   "name":"XYZ",
   "categoryTags":["ABC","DEF","GHI", "IJK"....]
}

I want to search all documents which have say categoryTags(atleast one of them or more) :
      "ABC" or "GHI" or "IJK" 
Can anyone suggest me a query for this use case?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of Term Filter or the Term Query. You can pass the query body as post parameter. Details can be easily found in ES docs.

```
  {
     "filter" : {
        "terms" : {
            "categoryTags" : ["ABC", "GHI", ...]
        }
      }
   }

   or 

   {
      "query" : {
           "term" : {"categoryTags" : ["ABC", "GHI", ...]}
      }
   }
```

Refer to [ES documents](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-filter.html).

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste below command at your webbrowser.

http://xx.xx.xx.xx:9200/index_v1/type/_search?q=categorytag:abc|ghi&size=50

i hope this is very useful to u .

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes this work and is what I was using till now, but I was looking for a full request body type query not the one where we pass everything in the uri. Thats when my problem started and I havent been able to write a query for that.

Comment: can u brief explain about ur request.i can't understood.